# Metaprogramming question involving has_many & belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

I have two classes:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity_type

  def belongs_to_cat_a?
    self.activity_category == ActivityCategory.category_a
  end

  def belongs_to_cat_b?
    self.activity_category == ActivityCategory.category_b
  end

end

class ActivityCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities

  def self.cat_a
    ActivityCategory.find_by_name("CatA")
  end

  def self.cat_b
    ActivityCategory.find_by_name("CatB")
  end
end
```

Using metaprogramming, I changed ActivityCategory to the following:

```
class ActivityCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities

  CATEGORIES = ['CatA', 'CatB']

  class << self
      CATEGORIES.each do |c|
          define_method "#{c.underscore.downcase}" do # for ex: cat_a
              find_by_name(c)
          end
      end
  end

end
```

Ok. Now imagine in the class Activity that I have about 12 methods to check which category it belongs to.
Seems like a perfect candidate to be DRY'ed up a bit using MP.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good candidate for MP. First, you are hard coding you categories, which right away is writing code, instead of generating it. If you want to return a true/false statement when asked if it belongs to a certain category, you could just do the following:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def belongs_to? activity
    activity_type.name == activity
  end

end
```

and execute as so...

```
a = Activity.save(:activity_category => ActivityCategory.new(:name => "CatA")
a.belongs_to? "CatA" #=> true
```

or am i missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a recommended way as this code tends to be a little difficult to maintain (Jed's solution is nicer), but you can just apply your same style of MP you already have:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity_type

  CATEGORIES = ['CatA', 'CatB']

  class << self
    CATEGORIES.each do |c|
      define_method "belongs_to_#{c.underscore.downcase}?" do # for ex: cat_a
        self.activity_category == ActivityCategory.send( "category_#{c[-1]}".to_sym )  
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd alter what you already have.

If you intercept it with method_missing, you can avoid hardcoding the category list.

```
class ActivityCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  alias_method :old_method_missing, :method_missing

  def self.method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if cat = self.class.find_by_name(method.to_s)
      return cat
    else
      old_method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    end
  end

end
```

This works because if the method called isn't detected, it will pass it to the old method missing. Just don't name any categories "find" or anything similar if you want to pull any tricks like this!

In the same manner, in activity, you can do

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity_type
  alias_method :old_method_missing, :method_missing

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if matchdata = /\Abelongs_to_category_(\w)\?/.match(method.to_s)
      return ActivityCategory.find_by_name(matchdata[1]) == ActivityCategory.send(matchdata[1].to_sym)
    else
      old_method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    end
  end

end
```

I'm not sure the syntax is entirely right, but you could investigate that general approach